# How I can prevent integers from truncating value while division in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C and here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
int a,b;
float division;

clrscr();

printf("Enter value of a :"); scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter value of b :"); scanf("%d",&b);

division = a/b;

printf("\nDivision : %.2f",division);

getch();

}
```

When I execute this code and enter values it does not return accurate output.
For example if `a = 15 & b = 10` then output is `1.00` and another example is `a = 10 & b=15` then output is `0.00`. Is there a way to prevent integers from truncating? **I can't take a and b as floats.**

Comment: Integer division truncates. I.e., the two operands are integers, so division will return an integer, but then it'll be cast to a floating point type

Comment: It is ok when I use a and b with float

Comment: @AftabAnsari, yes change the data type to either float or double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, integer division always truncates. However, you can do floating point division if you just cast (at least) one of your operands:

```
division = (float)a/b;
```